# Use mongodb mongoose find with RedExp

Tags: regex, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I read some post, and it works with one model, but when I try it with other models, it doesn't works. I have this:

```
function getimages(search, callback) {

   imagenmodel.find({ title: new RegExp(search) }, function (err, imagent){

       if (err) throw err;

       console.log(imagent);

       callback(imagent);

   });

}
```

The `console.log`shows me that the imagent object is empty, even if the RegExp letters coincide with some letters of a title. Maybe I use it in a wrong way, but I don't know how to do it properly. Ano solution for this...?

Thank's advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
imagenmodel.find({ title: new RegExp(reg) }, function (err, imagent){
```

should probably be

```
imagenmodel.find({ title: new RegExp(search) }, function (err, imagent){
```

because that's the function parameter.

Comment: True! I edited that, I wrote it wrong. The code is as you said, but stills no working

Comment: Could you add the value of search and some titles you are searching for. Maybe you could add your schema definition, too